# Discord Api bot not joining the voice channel consistently

Tags: python, discord

I have made a bot that joins the voice channel whenever a discord member joins said channel,but sometimes when the member leaves and joins back i get the error that the bot is already connected,so i added the is_connected function to check if the bot is already conected before attempting to join.For some reason this fuction works only half the time,if i join and leave the call mutiple times eventually it just stops joining and it leaves no error code,it just stops.
This is the code:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
  
  print("Logged in as {0.user}".format(client))

@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):

  if not before.channel and after.channel and member.id == 450333776485285919 or member.id==232855365082021890 or member.id==282234566066962433 or member.id==256759154524291074:
    
    channel = client.get_channel(988050675604803648)
    
    await is_connected()
    
    
  

@client.event
async def  is_connected():
    channel = client.get_channel(988050675604803648)
    voice_client=discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients)
    
    if(voice_client==None):
      
      await channel.connect()
    else:
      print("is connected:")
```

Did i use the function wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you created an entire function for is_connected() which isn't entirely necessary. You need to use that event within the on_voice_state_update to check if the bot is already connected to that current voice channel.

```
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):

  if not before.channel and after.channel and member.id == 450333776485285919 or member.id==232855365082021890 or member.id==282234566066962433 or member.id==256759154524291074:
    
channel = client.get_channel(988050675604803648)

if client.voice.is_connected():
  return print("already connected")
    
await channel.connect()
```